# Qt4 how to add 16px/32px/... icons for my application?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

how can I setup icons for my Qt application ? 
Do I have to provide 16px,32px icons and so on ? 
Or will Qt automagically resize them to fit current requirements ?

Comment: What other icon sizes are used by operating systems ?

Comment: I was able to find this site with icons sizes for different OSes. http://www.hicksdesign.co.uk/iconreference/ The question is how to add  many icons to application ?

Comment: You have to use platform-specific resource file specifications. Read my answer for how to integrate those into a QT app build process, but how to specify those resources depends on platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: It seems you're talking about the window icon of the top-level window.
Window icons can be set using `QWidget::setWindowIcon()`, and the default icon for new windows can be set using `QApplication::setWindowIcon()`. If your source image is of high enough resolution, Qt should automatically resize this icon for you to suit all occations.

This is described in the Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html), including info about how to set the embedded icon of a .exe file or OS X application.

Comment: I was thinking about the icon that is visible when you press alt+tab or the icon that apears in the taskbar or the icon visible in the top left corner of a window in windows.

Comment: In that case, create a QIcon and call Application::setWindowIcon(). Sub-windows can set their own icon using QWidget::setWindowIcon(). This is all in the first paragraph of my last link.

Comment: None of the answers (so far) address the actual question: how do you use different sized icons in Qt? Scaled-down icons generally look noisy.

Comment: @doug65536: It turns out that wasn't the question - which is why it's not the one answered :) To answer your question though, use QIcon::addFile or QIcon::addPixmap to specialize a QIcon for different sizes.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can fix my project. Trust me, I searched a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You mean the application-icon, which is shown from windows for the executable, in taskbar and on alt+tab?

Create an `yourprojekt.rc` and point to your icon:

```
  IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "./youricon.ico"
```

In the projektfile advice qmake to use the resourcefile:

```
  RC_FILE = YourProjekt.rc
```

For the `youricon.ico` I recommend to include the the icon in 16px, 24px, 32px, 48px and 256px. Afaik are these the sizes used by windows for small symbols (16px) to extra large symbols (256px).

If you don't have an image of an particular size in your ico, windows will resize another one to that size - but upsizing or downsizung 32px to/from 256px does not look so nice in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that You can store multiple images in *.ico file.

There is a nice free tool to build ico files
http://icofx.ro

Answer (score 0):

Qt can and will resize the icons.

Include a resource file to your project and use the resource editor to add icons.

Comment: But how will Qt know which icon to use in resource file ? I have many icons there - used in toolbars, buttons and so on.

Comment: I'm trying to be cross-platform so: Windows,Linux,MacOSX :) It seems that I have to call setWindowIcon() for every icon that I include in the resource file that is to be used as an application icon.